# In SwfitData, How to pass the result of @Query as Binding to view

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

I want to pass some queried data from SwiftData in other views that receive a Binding array. Like the example below:

```swift
struct View1: View {
    @Query var data: [MyModel]

    var body: some View {
        View2($data) // how to make the queried data array a Binding here?  
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    @Binding var data: [MyModel]

    ....
}
```

One solution I can think about is to make the data a @State. Querying the models in init function and assign them to the @State property of View1 before pass it to the View2.

```swift
struct View1: View {
    @State private var data: [MyModel] = []

    init() {
        // query the data here then assign them to the state property.
    }

    var body: some View {
        View2($data) 
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    @Binding var data: [MyModel]

    ....
}
```

But the problem is when the source of the SwiftData Model got updated, the @State property won't get updated accordingly. Since the @State is a personal property of the view. So the shortcoming of the solution is obvious.
Is There any good pattern can solve this problem without any side effects? Thanks!

Comment: Query is read-only, Binding is a two way connection. Also Binding is for value types Bindable is for Observable/Model

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a binding for that, it's just:

```
struct View1: View {
    @Query var data: [MyModel]

    var body: some View {
        View2(data) // how to make the queried data array a Binding here?  
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    let data: [MyModel]

    ....
}
```

Binding is for write access, which doesn't make sense for query results.